# Contentful - Push assets (images) and Metadata tags to Algolia search

Tags: reactjs, algolia, contentful

We are having an issue with Algolia Search. Basically we can not get the media url from Algolia and Metadata Tags (general tags) are also not getting back the data in Algolia, it only get use the ID which is not useful. Title and Description works perfectly fine, at the end of the day it just the text so I do not see the problem with that.

#### Payload

```
{
"title": "{ /payload/fields/heading/en-US}",
"description": "{ /payload/fields/shortDescription/en-US}",
"slug": "{ /payload/fields/slug/en-US}",
"imageId": "{ /payload/fields/mainImage/en-US}",
"metadata": "{ /payload/metadata/tags}"
}
```

#### Content Model

[image]

Comment: Same issue - any answers?